# Blazor propertychange strange behavior

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have created a searchable multi-select dropdown. I'm not sure if it is a possible bug or error in my code.

To reproduce perform the following:

1 Select first item

2 In input search box type "o" or "one"

3 FilteredItems's first checkbox is checked despite it not being in SelectedItems

4 On clearing the input search box typing "o" again displays without checked

[image]

```
<div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-light"
            @onclick="@ToggleSelectMenu"
            title="@ButtonHoverTitleText">
        @ButtonText
    </button>
</div>
<div hidden="@toggleSelectBox" class="shadow p-2 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
    <div class="m-1">
        <input class="form-control" @bind="FilterText" @bind:event="oninput" />
    </div>
    @foreach (var item in FilteredItems)
    {
        <label class="item">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" checked="@item.IsSelected"
               @onchange="_e => {SelectionChanged(item.Item, _e.Value);}" /><span>@item.Item</span>
        </label>
        <br />
    }
</div>
</div>
    <p>
        @string.Join(",", SelectedItems)
    </p>

@code {
    private string? _filterText;
    private bool toggleSelectBox = true;

    [Parameter] public List<string> Items { get; set; } = new List<string>() { "item", "one 1", "two 3", "last 4" };
    [Parameter] public List<string> SelectedItems { get; set; } = new();
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<List<string>> SelectedItemChanged { get; set; }
    public List<SelectedItem> FilteredItems { get; set; } = new();
    public string? ButtonText { get; set; } = "Nothing selected";
    public string? ButtonHoverTitleText { get; set; }

    public string? FilterText
    {
        get => _filterText;
        set
        {
            _filterText = value;
            FilteredItems = new();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_filterText))
            {
                foreach (var item in Items?.Where(x => x.ToLower().Contains(_filterText.ToLower())))
                {
                    FilteredItems.Add(new SelectedItem { Item = item, IsSelected = SelectedItems.Contains(item) });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in Items)
                {
                    FilteredItems.Add(new SelectedItem { Item = item, IsSelected = SelectedItems.Contains(item) });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Items?.ForEach(i => FilteredItems.Add(new SelectedItem { Item = i }));
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    public void ToggleSelectMenu()
    {
        toggleSelectBox = !toggleSelectBox;
        ClearSearchText();
    }
    private void ClearSearchText() => FilterText = null;

    public void SelectionChanged(string item, object checkedValue)
    {
        if ((bool)checkedValue)
        {
            if (!SelectedItems.Contains(item))
            {
                SelectedItems.Add(item);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (SelectedItems.Contains(item))
            {
                SelectedItems.Remove(item);
            }
        }
        ButtonHoverTitleText = SelectedItems.Any() ? string.Join(",", SelectedItems.Select(x => x)) : null;
        ButtonText = SelectedItems.Any()
            ? (SelectedItems.Count == 1 ? ButtonHoverTitleText : $"{SelectedItems.Count} items selected")
            : "Nothing selected";
        SelectedItemChanged.InvokeAsync(SelectedItems);
    }

    public class SelectedItem
    {
        public string? Item { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using [`@key` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-key-to-control-the-preservation-of-elements-and-components) in your `foreach`, that's usually the culprit of weird state when loops are involved.

Comment: Thanks a ton @JanJoneš! That's all it was @key directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70897851/blazor-propertychange-strange-behavior#comment125353416_70897851) gives the answer, but to explain more what is going on, here is what happens when you type an "o". Notice how `item` is being *replaced* by `one 1` and that nothing else changes. In other words, Blazor detects the amount necessary to update the DOM and applies those changes. This is usually what you want, however, when you are dynamically updating a group of items such as your case this behavior is undesirable. (Note: I added a `firstitem` attribute to the input below just to show it doesn't get updated).

[image]

The answer to that is to use `@key`:

```
<label class="item" @key=item>
```

When you do that, the DOM will be updated anytime the **value** of the key you specified changes. This will ensure that not only the text in span, but also the input element is updated. So as a rule of thumb, always use `@key` when you are adding/removing/reordering elements from a list. Also, I didn't mention above, but also when you reorder items, `@key` plays a vital role, as it ensures elements that didn't change are preserved.

Here is a link to the [documentation on @key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-key-to-control-the-preservation-of-elements-and-components).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation @Jesse Good.