# Is there any GetElementById in Blazor for C# Or just tell me why my Checkbox stays checked

Tags: c#, html, blazor, bootstrap-5

I need to change the "checked" attribute of a checkbox input element, depending on a models-property. So far very easy... but this "checked" is within a random list of li-elements generated by a list of models (representing an todo-element). This list can be filtered by ALL|ACTIVE|COMPLETED, which will be visually be shown on each element as a checked checkbox.

When i now filter for active elements, meaning all not yet checked elements, and hit the checkbox, my todo gets successfully be shifted into completed elements filter. BUT the checkbox at the old place of the element is still in new state. Remember: Was unchecked -> I checked it -> it moved right -> old place of element now holds a checked checkbox in filter of all active (unchecked) elements... I do not know why this happens... now I try to change the value of this checkbox by C# Code which seems not to be as easy as it sounded to me.

How can I achieve it/what is best practice in my case/WHAT IS THE PROBLEM OF THIS CHECKBOX?

Here my Code:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade @((filter.Equals(FilterEnum.All)) ? "show active" : null)" id="ex1-tabs-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ex1-tab-1">
            <ul class="list-group mb-0">
                @{
                    foreach (var item in vm.ShoppingList.ShopItems)
                    {
                        Attributes =
                            item.IsChecked ? new Dictionary<string, object>()
                            {
                                { "checked","checked" },
                            }
                            : new Dictionary<string, object>()
                            {

                            };

                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center border-0 mb-2 rounded"
                            style="background-color: #f4f6f7;">
                            <input id="@item.Id" class="form-check-input me-2" type="checkbox" aria-label="..." @attributes="Attributes"
                                   @onchange="eventArgs => { CheckboxClicked(item, eventArgs.Value); }" />
                            @{
                                if (item.IsChecked)
                                {
                                    <s>Cras justo odio @(item.Name))</s>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <p class="my-auto">Cras justo odio @(item.Name))</p>
                                }
                            }
                        </li>
                    }
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
```

@code {
Dictionary<string, object> Attributes { get; set; }

```
 void CheckboxClicked(KBuddy.Data.ShoppingList.ShopItem item, object checkedValue)
{
    var tempItem = vm.ShoppingList.ShopItems.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(item.Id));
    vm.ShoppingList.ShopItems.Remove(tempItem);
    tempItem.IsChecked = ((bool)checkedValue);
    vm.ShoppingList.ShopItems.Add(tempItem);
}
```

}

Result in Pictures:

[Active-filter before checking TestItem_0][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/08m4d.png

[Active-filter after checked TestItem_0. You can see the checked checkbox, which should not be here at TestItem_2!][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdIjF.png

[TestItem_0 correctly moved to Completed-filter][3]
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr1mo.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, anytime you generate lists dynamically, always make sure to use the `@key` directive.

You can read more about the directive [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-key-to-control-the-preservation-of-elements-and-components) and [here](https://blazor-university.com/components/render-trees/optimising-using-key/).

But basically, if you do not use a `@key`, the order between your list of objects and list in the HTML is not preserved. That is why you are seeing the behavior you mentioned:

> Remember: Was unchecked -> I checked it -> it moved right -> old place
> of element now holds a checked checkbox in filter of all active
> (unchecked)

You can set the `@key` like this:

```
<li @key="item" ...
```

[Here is a link to a previous answer of mine which explains it in more detail.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70910147/906773)

Comment: Thank you so much... just works like a charm! So the '@key' attribute tells the system to update this and all child elements on a change of '@keys' value... great little thing! Thank you!